# How can I create text to speech using PhoneGap on the android?

Tags: android, cordova, text-to-speech, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phonegap, but i know how to use phonegap in android .But i want to know that

How can I create (text to speech) tts library  using PhoneGap on the android.?

I have a (Text-to-speech) tts library which is native code. I want to use this tts library on the android using phonegap. Can anybody suggest me.....plz help.... i am trying for long time....plz give some sample example of this if you can so that it will be easier to understand for all....

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this Github project

[TTS plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/macdonst/TTS)